# Boost Dynamic Properties with Custom get property

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to use boost::dynamic properties to multiple properties to the Graphviz output.

I am familiar with custom property writer ([How to print a graph in graphviz with multiple properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369115/how-to-print-a-graph-in-graphviz-with-multiple-properties-displayed)), but I am trying to do the same thing with dynamic properties.  How do we write the above edge property writer using the dynamic properties in the following code? I want to write if else statements on the values of the weight and capacity as in if(weight <5 && capacity <5) then color = red and so on.

```
boost::dynamic_properties dp/*(ignore_other_properties)*/;
dp.property("node_id", get(&vert::name, g));
dp.property("color", get(??,g));
write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
```

Comment: Huh. What color do you want it to have? There is no mention of it in the linked answer. If anything, the trick would likely be exactly the same: `get(&edge::color, g)` (assuming that `edge` has a member named `color`)

Comment: I have edited the question to mention that part. Edge has weight and capacity as its members and I want to use these two properties to write an if-else block to assign colors in the output graph.  In the linked answer, I can do that in the operator() function but how do we that using the dp.property()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See some options here: [map set/get requests into C++ class/structure changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863061/map-set-get-requests-into-c-class-structure-changes/27863767#27863767)

You can either transform the result of one property map, or you can use a functional property map altogether.

## Transforming values:

An example of using dynamic properties to transform a color property is here: [Manually colouring of boost's graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949480/manually-colouring-of-boosts-graphs/29956404#29956404)

## Functional map:

- [How to use boost::graph dijkstra's algorithm if vertex properties are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847186/how-to-use-boostgraph-dijkstras-algorithm-if-vertex-properties-are-pointers/41858441#41858441)
- My preference would be to use a member function and bind it using the transform_value_property_map as shown above, e.g. [Using boost graph library with a custom class for vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857868/using-boost-graph-library-with-a-custom-class-for-vertices/46858909#46858909)
- But here is an example using `function_property_map` as well [boost dijkstra_shortest_paths: can't extract (or find?) the path (path contains a cycle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367649/boost-dijkstra-shortest-paths-cant-extract-or-find-the-path-path-contains/48371770#48371770)

Note that you also have `make_constant_property_map` (e.g. [Boost Dynamic Properties with Custom get property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104768/boost-dynamic-properties-with-custom-get-property))

Comment: Thanks. This perfectly fits the case I was trying to solve. I was not aware of the make_transform_value_property_map.